# EJB components inheritance

Tags: jakarta-ee

I have an issue with EJB components inheritance.

I have following components.

```
@Remote
public interface A {

    void myMethod();
}
```

And implementation class as below:

```
@Stateless
public class AImpl implements A {

    @Override
    void myMethod(){}
}
```

Caller class as below:

```
public class Caller {

    @EJB
    A bean;

    void someMethod{
        bean.myMethod();
    }
}
```

The above 3 classes are our framework classes I should not change the code and I can use them. In my case I have written my customized class by extending the class `AImpl` and overriden the method like as below.

```
@Remote(A.class)
@Stateless
class AImpl1 extends AImpl {

    @Override
    void myMethod(){}
}
```

But when ever my caller invokes the method `bean.myMethod()` every time `AImpl.myMethod()` is being executed, instead I want to execute my overridden method. Is there any way to pass my bean at run time with out changing above 3 classes?

I know if I can change Caller class with `@EJB(name="AImpl1")` then my overridden method get executes but I can't do that.

Comment: Check this out: [EJB Inheritance is Different From Java Inheritance](http://piotrnowicki.com/2013/03/ejb-inheritance-is-different-from-java-inheritance/).

Comment: Hi Nicholas, I have gone through it. But in my case I can't change the caller like @EJB(name="AImpl1"). I need some thing I can inject to it at run time with out changing the framework class. I mean I want by configuration changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the CDI managed bean solution is right.

1., Configurable solution:
Instead of derivation use multi implementor of the A interface, mark them with the @Alternative annotations + register the apropriate implementor in the beans.xml.

```
@Alternative
@RequestScoped
public class AImpl1 implements A {...}

@Alternative
@RequestScoped
public class AImpl2 implements A {...}

public class Caller {
  @Inject
  private A bean;
  ...
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
   bean-discovery-mode="annotated">

  <alternatives>
    <class>x.AImpl2</class>
  </alternatives>
</beans>
```

2., Runtime solution
Use @Producer + @Produces annotations to create implementor instances depending on some runtime state. The method marked with the @Produces @AImplementor creates the instances when the @Inject @AImplementor marked field/etc need them.

```
public class AImplFactory {
  private static final int IMPL1 = 0;
  private static final int IMPL2 = 1;

  @Setter
  private AImplType aImplType = IMPL2;

  @Produces
  @AImplementor
  public A createAImplementor() {
    switch ( aImplType ) {
      case IMPL1: return new AImpl1();
      case IMPL2: return new AImpl2();
    }
  }
}

public class Caller {
  @Inject
  @AImplementor
  private A bean;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this group and not aware of this. I have accepted it. Thank you.